# Image Resolution in Deep Learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, object-detection

Let me summarize my problem as follows,

I have been facing a memory error whenever I try to train a model with my custom dataset. Later, I noticed that some of the images are very high resolution compared to other images in the same dataset. However their size was not that greater.

There is a image resizer in the my pre-trained model, so I thought the situation I mentioned above wouldn't be a problem, but I could not be sure. Does it cause a problem?

Comment: what's the `batch_size` in your `pipeline.config` file?

Comment: @NicolasGervais it is currently 8, I reduced it to 4 before, but it continued to give me the same error.

Comment: Try only 1, see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could be a potential source for memory error. Usually, memory error happens because of two reasons, the first is a high image size (maybe even the resized dimensions are high) and batch size.

These are kind of related in some sense. If you use a higher image size, you must use a lower batch size to compensate for the memory. However, don't reduce the image size too much. If you think that despite having a reasonable image size you face memory errors, you have to go with reducing the batch size. Usually, the input image size varies from model to model.